# Disabling session when clicking Log out button and redirecting to Login page with message

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

i want to disable sesssion on button click in an jsp page
i know:

```
<button type="button">Log out!</button>
<%session.invalidate();%>
```

how should i implement this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On click of button make a GET to a servlet, and in servlet invalidate the session and redirect it to login page

```
<a href="/app/logOutServlet">Log Out</a>
```

in servlet

```
doGet(....){
request.getSession().invalidate();
response.sendRedirect("URL_TO_LOGIN_PAGE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it:

- The button redirects to a Servlet, using either a form or JavaScript code (I would go for the form, I'm not such a big fan of JavaScript everywhere)
- The Servlet invalidates the session, using `request.getSession().invalidate();`